# How do I call a 'call' object in R

Tags: r

I have a function that returns, among other things, a call generated by match.call() that in this case returns

```
build_model.kd_data(data = kd_data, optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), loss = loss_poisson)
```

How do I then call that again, effectively repeating the entire function again?

Answer (score 4):

You use `eval` to evaluate a call.

Although `eval` is sometimes abused via the usually inappropriate `eval(parse(...))` idiom, it is perfectly reasonable to use it on a call captured by `match.call` or constructed through the `call` or `as.call` functions, as stated in the docs for `?call`

> Note that `call()` and `as.call()`, when applicable, are much preferable to these `parse()` based approaches.

Obviously, we don't have your data to reproduce your example, but here's a minimal example of an S3 class that returns a call captured by `match.call` put through `eval` to reproduce the original call:

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

model$call
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

eval(model$call)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           wt  
#>      37.285       -5.344
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: My issue was that it was not finding build_model.kd_data, as I have been calling the generic build_model. I have resolved it now by changing the call after match.call:
call[[1]] <- call("build_model")
Is there a better was of match.call not including the class?

Comment: @jackahall sorry, you didn't mention that in your question, nor which package `build_model` came from, nor did you include any data to reproduce your problem. I assumed you were asking a more generic question since you would know that no-one could answer the specific question with the information you provided. Anyway, substituting the generic as the first element is a reasonable way to do it. The alternative is to `eval` the call within the package namespace, but this is probably more problematic than the solution you hit upon yourself - this idiom is used a lot in the `stats` package